# Why am I not able to wget these types of links?

Tags: video, wget, webm, youtube-dl

https://r4---sn-a5m7lnek.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?requiressl=yes&id=bfcd54f32577fad7&itag=22&source=webdrive&app=texmex&ip=2605:e000:608a:400:f4cd:ff6:3353:dcc&ipbits=8&expire=1464424582&sparams=expire,id,ip,ipbits,itag,mm,mn,ms,mv,nh,pl,requiressl,source&signature=1701A7336E5CB650393D0AE2FC4B24388F033594.7795C4BFED9863E57BBADCA3ACD8FF33D79A8018&key=cms1&pl=32&cms_redirect=yes&mm=31&mn=sn-a5m7lnek&ms=au&mt=1464414847&mv=m&nh=IgpwcjAzLmxheDAyKgkxMjcuMC4wLjE

I am wondering what is preventing me from wgeting this file. When I look at it, it is a video on a page right...?

When I try to wget (or youtube-dl), it gives me this error:
ERROR 403: Forbidden.

but why?

Comment: Does it work if you run each time per download? I don't use `Youtube-dl` so I don't know how correct it is, but... What makes you think it's a webm file? There is no `&mime=video/webm` shown in your link. Also it's possible the token has expired and you must generate a new one before getting bytes access (see variable:  `&expire=1464424582`). Your `&ip=2605:e0...etc` doesn't look right, it should be like example `&ip=207.244.90.78`. I think command line method makes the IP become LocalHost? (I'm used to getting via http requests so it looks strange to me). Hopefully IP is not an issue.

Comment: In short... to get a fresh token just pass your link through Youtube-dl each time you need a download. You cannot re-use the same link later on. Make sure the video is not removed. If all fails... Show me a youtube link to some movie trailer, now show me what your 480p link looks like (taken from Youtube-dl) and I'll compare with my code's version of link...

Comment: Will the video load for you at all?

Comment: Oh and yes, I made a mistake, it is an mp4 file.

Comment: I looked at your comment again and again... I really didn't understand what you said.. Sorry ): could you rephrase it for me?

Comment: The video does not load for me. Also note that Youtube direct file links always expire after a short time (it's how their server works). So your shown link could never work since one hour after posting. So **each time you must get a new download link** (like the first time you got above link, do same process everytime you want to save). **(1)** Pass YT link to Youtube-dl, **(2)** Get file link as result, **(3)** Result is what you `wget` to disk... That's it, do this everytime to save a file (even if exact same file later on, pass the YT link and a get a fresh link (token) for downloading...)

Comment: It was not a youtube direct file link... Also, sorry for asking, but what did you mean by "passing through youtube-dl"? Did you mean "youtube-dl
https://r4---sn-a5m7lnek.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?requiressl=ye..." ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why am I not able to wget these types of links?

Because they are not valid Youtube links that **Youtube-dl** can use... It wants a browser link (page) but here you give it a file download link.

If your link does not include `youtube.com/watch?v=` you will never be able to `wget` that link.

> Also, sorry for asking, but
>   what did you mean by "passing through youtube-dl"? Did you mean
>   `youtube-dl r4---sn-a5m7lnek.googlevideo.com/…;` ?

A Youtube link is always presented as `https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VIDEO_ID`.

For example where **VIDEO_ID** is something like `Dm_xLDvCrNI`.
The full link to pass to **Youtube-dl** is :
**[`https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Dm_xLDvCrNI`](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Dm_xLDvCrNI)**

> It was not a Youtube direct file link...

If your link begins `https://r4---` then it is actually a **direct link to the file on Youtube server**. This is what **Youtube-dl** itself gets when you give it a Youtube video link & then allows you to save the file. 
Youtube servers begins like example `https://r2---` and go upwards to `https://r9---`

For example with this **[video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Dm_xLDvCrNI)** : The MP4 direct file link is shown below (play in browser or save file) : 
https://r2---sn-5uaeznzk.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?ipbits=0&ratebypass=yes&key=yt6&upn=oGVhc2fiEPA&fexp=9405824,9416126,9416891,9421734,9422596,9428398,9429044,9431012,9432028,9432379,9432683,9432971,9433096,9433655,9433946,9434802,9435329,9435527,9435850,9435876,9436051,9437067,9437323,9437403&itag=18&mn=sn-5uaeznzk&pl=23&source=youtube&mm=31&ip=108.62.18.190&mime=video/mp4&requiressl=yes&expire=1464594226&mv=m&mt=1464572379&ms=au&id=o-AAoZ2sMU-9ULInZjN6ugmhG_8hBJeCQC1J7r9oDtZAKc&lmt=1458188004221288&sparams=dur,id,initcwndbps,ip,ipbits,itag,lmt,mime,mm,mn,ms,mv,nh,pl,ratebypass,requiressl,source,upn,expire&signature=10879388ACE74DA8C035A2D6723656A57268B106.A6BA3A7DFFD8EF6A168572F838F63DCADADFEE67&dur=149.652&initcwndbps=8983750&sver=3&nh=IgpwcjA0LmF0bDIyKg03Mi4xNC4yMTMuMTkz&title=Zootropolis+-+UK+Trailer+2+-+OFFICIAL+Disney+%7C+HD

PS: Link may not work by the time you read this, but the point is made about differences of expected links & what a direct link looks like.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Then how can I download those types of videos...? ):

Comment: You don't. When the access token has expired those links mean nothing now... If you need such a link, then first you must at least find the video title and search Youtube, when found pass that Youtube's page link to **Youtube-dl**. In my posted link the title is "Zootropolis - UK Trailer 2 - OFFICIAL Disney HD" as shown towards link ending... Do you have titles mentioned in your links?

Comment: You see this link? https://kissanime.to/Anime/Kiznaiver/Episode-001?id=124602 Scroll down and click "If the player does not work, CLICK HERE to use your device's player/try to disable IPv6 or change server" and click "click here". It takes you to that link that i specified. Again, I don't think that a youtube channel is uploading those.

Comment: Or a link like that.

Comment: I want to download the video that is being played, they are both the same link

Comment: video* They are both the same video*

Comment: Yeah it may not be a Youtube Channel but for storage it's using Google Video (Google owns Youtube) so that's why the server links are very similar. I don't know how you're gunna use `wget` or **Youtube-dl** (command line is not best for this task) but the links are in the HTML source code & written as Base64 text. So you need to make a program that reads the HTML and extracts that Base64 text, then decodes it to normal text (which now shows as the actual link you can paste in browser to play or save video MP4).

Comment: You can try it manually... View the HTML source. Find a section called `<select id="selectQuality">` and following options are `<option value="...some Base64 text..." >1080p</option>` etc... Just copy the text between the `" "` quotes and paste it in top box of this **[B64 Converter](http://base64decode.net/)** now hit `decode` button and voila!!! you have the MP4 link (try `wget` on that URL). If you want it automatic then write a program. Dunno if you code in PHP or Python or JS or whatever. For example with PHP you can decode B64 & also download the MP4 file to disk.

Comment: Okay! Thanks! I had no idea!